# perform delete row in sqlite table

Tags: android, sqlite

i have one table call listTable and productTable . I perform sqlite delete function in listTable , but something wrong in my coding . Inside productTable have Foreign key reference to primary key in listTable .

SQLiteHelper.java

```
     public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
            public static final String dbName = "shoppingDB1.db";
            public static final int dbVersion = 1;
            public static final String listTable = "ShoppingList";
            public static final String listId = "ShopingList_Id";
            public static final String listName = "ShopingList_Name";

            public static final String productTable = "Product";
            public static final String product_id = "Product_Id";
            public static final String productName = "Product_Name";
            public static final String product_FId = "Product_FId";
            private static final String CREATE_SHOPPLINGLIST_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                    + listTable
                    + " ("
                    + listId
                    + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + listName
                    + " TEXT ")";

            private static final String CREATE_PRODUCT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS "
                    + productTable
                    + " ("
                    + product_id
                    + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + productName
                    + " TEXT, "+ product_FId
                + " INTEGER NOT NULL,   "
                             FOREIGN KEY ("
                + product_FId
                + ") REFERENCES "
                + listTable
                + " ("
                + listId
                + ")
         public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_SHOPPLINGLIST_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_PRODUCT_TABLE);
}
        public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
        if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
            // Enable foreign key constraints
            db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
        }
    }
```

ComicsData.java

```
public class ComicsData {
public ComicsData(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context);
    }

public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
public void deleteList(String myid) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] arg={myid};
        try{
        database.delete(SQLiteHelper.listTable, SQLiteHelper.listId+ " = ?",arg);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("cannot", e.toString());
        }
    }
```

error message

```
12-02 17:27:46.232: E/error(21668): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
```

deleteList(String myid) will display error if there have product inside the list .
anyone know what is my problem ? should the foreign key problem  . I passing listId to deleteList(String myid)

Comment: What error do you get, exactly?

Comment: i cannot delete list if i added product inside to list
12-02 17:24:04.936: E/cannot(21033): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed

Comment: I feel its a foreign key constraint error. Write a query to delete Product_FId and ListID together from the tables. Just try it.It should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your products have the list id as a foreign key.  You cannot delete a list which contains a product since all products which have that list id as a foreign key would then belong to a non-existent list.

You have set constraints on (`db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");`) therefore SQLite will not allow you to do this and throws the exception you are seeing.

In other words, the constraint says that all products that have a list id must refer to an existing list.

To fix this, you could null all productTable.listIDs that reference the list you want to delete.  To do this automatically, add `ON DELETE SET NULL` to your constraint.

You should read this:

http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html